# How do I build a crystal report from the bottom of the page, up? (Whitespace before the data)

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to build a report that starts at the bottom of a page and grows upwards instead of a report that starts at the top of the page and grows downwards.  How could I do this?

--Edit--

For clarification, below is an image depicting the way I need to construct the report.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to have the whitespace at the top of the page and the data at the bottom of the page, instead of the more traditional look of data at the top of the page and whitespace at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about what the request is, I don't believe there is a way for the report to run from the bottom up, but you could possibly do a couple things to fake the system out.

For example you can do something like in the following link to put your summaries in the header:

[Crystal Reports: global variable running total not displaying in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662322/crystal-reports-global-variable-running-total-not-displaying-in-header)

Then you can play with the sorting of the details if you need the rows to go in decending order.

Hope this helps.

[EDIT] I see you updated your question so I'll add an update to my answer.

One more thing you can try out is to play around with the Print at the Bottom of the Page and Keep Together properties of the sections. I haven't tried this, but one thing you may be able to do is put the section at the bottom of the page and perhaps find a way to have the section grow from there. You will have an issue if the page goes to another page and though it seems possible in my head that the section could grow while being placed at the bottom of the page I haven't tried it so it might not work. I am just throwing it out there for one more thing you can try. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

1. Create an empty report with your headers and related text
2. Put a subreport displaying your data in the report footer and set the sort order for the subreport query to descending.
3. In the report footer properties, select `Print at bottom of page`

I tried it with some sample data and it works, but I'm not sure what will happen if your data goes to two pages.